# Startup Application issue

Tags: startup-applications

Have a strange issue with an application that is starting up many times. 
Synergy ( for sharing mouse and keyboard) is starting 10-20 times ie there are around 20minstances of the application when I first log in.

I've checked StartUp applications and Synergy isn't even listed!
AFAIK there isn't an application specific preference that enables auto start.

Comment: Anything in /etc/xdg/autostart?

Comment: What version Synergy?